# Special group by (based on succeeding values) in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I would like to perform a special group by statement, in other programming languages I would use some kind of loop, but I have no idea on how to tackle this using sql. Hope that you guys can be of some help. Bit of sample data

```
NR  date    Code
2   1-1-2013    6
2   1-1-2013    6
2   3-1-2013    6
2   4-1-2013    7
2   5-1-2013    6
2   5-1-2013    5
3   1-1-2013    1
3   2-1-2013    1
3   2-1-2013    6
3   3-1-2013    7
```

I would like to do a group by on NR and Code. However I  don't want to group non-succeeding Code's (they are sorted on NR and date). The desired output will make it clear i think:

```
NR  Code    #
2   6       3
2   7       1
2   6       1
2   5       1
3   1       2
3   6       1
3   7       1
```

After this I would like to cast it to this format (could be another question, but illustrates my need for a solution for the problem above):

```
NR  Code_string #_string
2   6,7,6,5     3,1,1,1
3   1,6,7       2,1,1
```

If I did not provide a good example, please tell, this is my first question for sql (learned alot of R using SO)

Comment: What dbms are you using (i.e. SQL Server, MySQL, etc)?

Comment: Given that rows in an RDBMs have no order, in what sense does one record succeed another? Further (and not unrelated), a PRIMARY KEY is a prerequisite of a relational table.

Comment: @Jeff Sorry, good question: Microsoft SQL 2008. Further, because I am new I don't really know about indexing in MySQL.. To go into your point, one succeeds the other when the Code changes (ordered by the date). Also if you know a solution by adding ID or index or something, I am looking at all possebilities

Answer (score -1):

```
select NR, Code, count(*) from yourdatabasename
group by NR, Code
order by NR, Code
```

This command should satisfy yor first desired output.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please look at OP's desired output more carefully -- particularly the two instances of code 6.

Comment: @Jeff, You are right, i answered probably to fast. The next time i will look more carefully to the question.